# Linked List - Error

Tags: c, linked-list

Good day!

Our teacher asked us to make a student list using a linked list. His condition is to add new student info into a list in a way that it will be sorted according to the grades of the student in descending order.  An error occurs every time i run the program. My code is as follows. Am i on the right path or am i missing something important? What causes the error? Your reply would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
typedef struct student{
       char name[11];
       unsigned int grade;
       struct student* next;       
    }NODE;

int main (void){
    NODE *head, *std;
    std = new_student();
}
```

Comment: ... and your while loop in add_student returns a value in the very first iteration

Comment: "It closes the program without any error message" - if your program works, it will read the input and then exit without any message.

Comment: As far as your education is concerned, now is probably as good a time as any to learn to use the debugger :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the bug is probably that you don't initialize `head` to NULL in `main` before passing it to `add_student`, but there are some other issues:

- gets can overrun the buffer if you enter too many characters of input for the name.
- as yurib says, the loop in `add_student` always returns on the first attempt
- you don't check the return from `malloc`, but that's *not* going to be the problem.
- you haven't forward-declared the functions you call.
- you haven't included `<stdlib.h>` (for malloc) or `<stdio.h>` (for printf).

Comment: @Steve Jessop what are the other issues?

Comment: @newbie: sorry, was just adding them.

Comment: @Steve Jessop okay thanks. i just didn't include all my codes. I already deleted the return in my while loop.. what do you mean i didn't check the return from malloc? thank you again.

Comment: @newbie: if there is insufficient free memory available to satisfy the request, `malloc` is specified to return a null pointer. Of course your program uses only a tiny amount of memory, so that's not happening here, but in general you should always be aware of the ways that functions you call can fail, and know how to handle failure. In this case, and often with failed memory allocation, there's not much you can do on failure other than exit, but in other cases error-handling can get quite involved, so it's best to start with simple cases.

Comment: So for example you could add `if (temp == NULL) { printf("Out of memory\n"); exit(1);}`, or you could add `if (temp == NULL) return temp;`, and say that callers of `new_student` should check *that* return value too. Although if you can't allocate enough memory for a NODE, there's a reasonable chance that nothing is working any more, so whether you'd actually see the message is another matter. It does mean that any crash isn't your fault, though, it's the OS's fault for failing in low-memory situations.

Answer (score 3):

```
NODE *head, *std;
head = null;
std = null    
std = new_student();
head = add_student(head, std);
```

Try that. You dont initialize head, and when

```
if (head == NULL) return to_add;
```

on add_student, head containts garbage value.

**Edit1:** Also keep in mind

```
NODE *curr_std, *prev_std = NULL;
```

is NOT equivalent to

```
NODE * curr_std = NULL;
NODE * prev_std = NULL:
```

if thats what you wanted to write then you should:

```
NODE *curr_std = NULL, *prev_std = NULL;
```

but the way you did it does not affect your program.

**Edit2:**

```
while (curr_std != NULL && to_add->grade < curr_std->grade){
    prev_std = curr_std;
    curr_std = curr_std->next;
}
prev_std->next = to_add;
to_add->next = curr_std;
return head;
```

is a bit weird. That return head; shouldn't really be there. You don't "refresh" your LL that way.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` in the `while` loop looks very suspicious, since that means the code after the loop can never be reached.

Also, dangerous to use plain `gets()` into a 11-char array; very easy to get overflow. Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2):

First error everyone makes, forgot to init vars:

```
NODE *head=NULL, *std=NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler should tell you about some errors before we do. This is the important warning `gcc` gave me:

```
1209.c:18:10: warning: 'head' is used uninitialized in this function
```

Comment: Make sure to enable your warnings (`-W -Wall` on the command line if you're on GCC).